# Prove that a function is convex if and only if it meets this condition

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that a continuous function defined on a convex domain is convex if and only if $$f\left(\frac{x+y}{2}\right) \leqslant \frac{f(x) + f(y)}{2},  \text{for all }x,y \in D$$

Comment: One direction is easy. For the other direction you can prove $f(\lambda x + (1-\lambda) y) \le \lambda f(x) + (1-\lambda) f(y)$ for $\lambda$ of the form $2^{-k}$ where $k \ge 0$ is an integer. Then use continuity to fill in the gaps.

Comment: @Mathinator What's your definition of a convex function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first prove that for any positive integer $k$ and points
$x_1, x_2, . . . , x_{2^k}$ , we have $$f\left(\frac{x_1+x_2+\dots+x_{2^k}}{2^k}\right) \leqslant \left(\frac{f(x_1)+f(x_2)+\dots+f(x_{2^k})}{2^k}\right) $$ The base case is the statement of the problem. The inductive step:
$$f\left(\frac{x_1+x_2+\dots+x_{2^k}+x_{2^k+1}+\dots+x_{2^{k+1}}}{2^{k+1}}\right) \leqslant \frac{f\left(\frac{x_1+x_2+\dots+x_{2^k}}{2^k}\right)+f\left(\frac{x_{2^k+1}+\dots+x_{2^{k+1}}}{2^{k}}\right)}{2}$$
$$\leqslant  \frac{\left(\frac{f(x_1)+f(x_2)+\dots+f(x_{2^k})}{2^k}\right)+ \left(\frac{f(x_{2^k+1})+\dots+f(x_{2^{k+1}})}{2^{k}}\right)}{2}$$ 
$$= \frac{f(x_1)+\dots+f(x_{2^k+1})}{2^{k+1}}$$
Next, we show that
$$\frac{f(x_1+x_2+x_3+\dots+x_n)}{n} \leqslant \frac{f(x_1)+f(x_2)+f(x_3)+\dots+f(x_n)}{n} $$
Assuming that it holds for any n points, we prove that it holds for $n-1$ as well. Consider the points $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{n-1}$ and define $\frac{x_n = x_1+\dots+x_{n-1}}{n-1}$. Using the induction hypothesis we can write, 
$$f\left(\frac{x_1+\dots+x_{n-1}+ \frac{x_n = x_1+\dots+x_{n-1}}{n-1}}{n}\right) \leqslant \left(\frac{f(x_1)+\dots+f(x_{n-1})+f\left( \frac{x_n = x_1+\dots+x_{n-1}}{n-1}\right)}{n}\right)$$ which is the same as 
$$f\left(\frac{x_1+\dots+x_{n-1}}{n-1}\right) \leqslant \frac{f(x_1)+f(x_2)+\dots+f(x_{n-1})}{n-1} + \frac{1}{n}f\left(\frac{x_1+\dots+x_{n-1}}{n-1}\right)$$ 
Moving the last term to the right gives us the required inequality. Starting
with a sufficiently large power of 2 we can cover the case of any positive integer n. In the inequality
$$f\left(\frac{x_1+\dots+x_{n-1}+x_n}{n}\right) \leqslant 
\frac{f(x_1)+f(x_2)+\dots +f(x_n)}{n}$$
that we just proved, for some $m < n$ set $x_1 = x_2 = \dots = x_m = x \text{ and } x_{m+1} = x_{m+2} =
\dots = x_n = y$. Then 
$$ f\left( \frac{m}{n}x + \left(1 - \frac{m}{n}\right)y\right) \leqslant 
 \frac{m}{n}f(x) + \left(1 - \frac{m}{n}\right)f(y)$$
Because $f$ is continuous we can pass to the limit with $\frac{m}{
n}$
→ λ to obtain the desired
$$f(\lambda x + (1- \lambda)y) \leqslant \lambda f(x) + (1- \lambda) f(y) $$
which characterises convex functions.